# "Convexity" of a family of distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution, exponential-distribution, convex-geometry

Let $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Consider a family of CDFs $\mathcal{X}$ that contains every CDF $X$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ with increasing hazard rate (IHR) which satisfies $$\mathbb{P}[x>y]=\alpha,$$ where $x\sim X$ and
$y\sim \textrm{Exponential}(1)$ are independent. I want to show that $\mathcal{X}$ is "convex", in some sense. A mixture of two members of $\mathcal{X}$ satisfies the above equality, but may not have IHR. A convolution of two members of $\mathcal{X}$ satisfies the IHR property but not necessarily the above equation. Are there "natural" addition and scalar multiplication operators defined on $\mathcal{X}$ under which this set is convex?

Comment: What does "convex" mean here? I'm pretty confused given the context.

Comment: Convexity means that if $a,b\in\mathcal{X}$, then $z*a+(1-z)*b\in\mathcal{X}$, for $z\in[0,1]$ and the properly defined scalar multiplication and addition operators discussed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact $\mathcal{X}$ is convex if scalar multiplication is defined as speeding up time and addition is defined as convolution.